# Need to determine the number of bytes downloaded using Winsock and recv

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, recv

I have code that uses a blocking socket to receive data via a call to recv. Everything works just fine. However there is no way to report to the user the number of bytes downloaded at any point in the process. I'm assuming that to be able to do this I would need to make multiple calls to recv, and report after each call? Or is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: recv will tell you how many bytes it received... and the only way to download all your data is through multiple calls to receive I presume. You could increment the total # of bytes received each time recv is called, but perhaps include some timing logic to only report it in intervals of x seconds?

Comment: This is what I assumed - multiple calls to receive, each call downloading a set number of bytes (and checking the return value to ensure that this number was actually received).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `recv` does the following:

> recv returns the number of bytes received and the buffer pointed to by the buf parameter will contain this data received.

So you could create an `int received` and accumulate the bytes received that are returned by `recv` until `recv` there is no more to receive, then report the total accumulated in your `received` variable.

Comment: Thanks, with the current code generally only one call to recv is needed to download the data. My logic does run in a loop though to ensure the expected amount is actually downloaded. Looks like I will need to modify this so that only a set number of bytes is downloaded in each iteration, and report the total after each call.

Comment: @AndrewKlinkhamer If one recv() call downloads all the data, there *is* no progress to report to the user. You could display zero before the recv() and the total bytes afterwards, but that's pretty pointless. It sounds like the payload must be very small idiot all comes in one chunk, which also suggests there is little point in reporting progress.